# Verifying service calls IRepository method that is defined in IGenericRepository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I  have a service let's say `Foo` service class.

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooRepository _repository;
    private readonly ISomeService _eventService;

    public FooService(IFooRepository repository, ISomeService eventService)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Foo> GetFoos(bool isDeleted = true)
    {
        var foos= _repository.GetList(x => x.IsDeleted == isDeleted).ToList();
        return !foos.Any() ? new List<Foo>(): foos;
    }

}
```

Here is `IFooRepository`

```
public interface IFooRepository : IGenericRepository<Foo>
{

}
```

and here is `IGenericRepository`

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
{

    IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav);

}
```

In my test I want to verify that FooService's `GetFoos` method calls `GetList` method

*This is what I tried*

```
[TestClass]
public class FooServiceTest
{
    private IQueryable<Foo> _foos;
    private Mock<IFooRepository> _fooRepository;
    private FooService _fooService;
    private Mock<ISomeService> _someService;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {

        _foos = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo
            {                  
                EmailId = "a@a.com",                  
                IsDeleted = false,                 
            },
            new Foo
            {                  
                EmailId = "a@a.com",                  
                IsDeleted = true,                 
            },       
        }.AsQueryable();           
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetGetFoos_CallsGetList()
    {
        //Arrange
        var foos= _foos.Where(x => x.IsDeleted).ToList();    
        _fooRepository = new Mock<IFooRepository>();         
        _fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(x => x.IsDeleted)).Returns(foos);
        _someServiceMock = new Mock<ISomeService>();
        _fooService = new FooService(_fooRepository.Object, _someServiceMock.Object);
        //Act
        _fooService.GetFoos(true);

        //Assert
        _fooRepository.Verify(m=>m.GetList(x=>x.IsDeleted), Times.Once());

    }
}
```

But I get argument null exception in following line

```
var foos= _repository.GetList(x => x.IsDeleted == isDeleted).ToList();
```

Any clue why this is happening even though I am saying `Returns(foos)` during setup.

Also how do I verify the interface method was called?

Comment: I'd try to change the test like so: `_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>())).Returns(foos);`


If you want to assert what expression is passed in, try `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>capturedExpression = null;`

`_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>())).Returns((Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> e ) => { capturedExpression  = e; 
return foos; });`

`Assert.IsTrue(capturedExpression.Compile()(_foos[1]));`

`Assert.IsFalse(capturedExpression.Compile()(_foos[0]));`

Comment: to verify the method was called you can also change the last it a bit more:`_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>())).Returns((Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> e ) => { capturedExpression = e; return foos; }).Verifiable();` then ` _fooRepository.Verify(m=>m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>()), Times.Once());`

However, if it is not called, then `capturedExpression` is null (that technique is known as implicit assertion)

Comment: you can put it as answer I can accept it

Comment: Create a method that is called `GetDeleted()` and verify that instead of having such a leaky abstraction! I see you're trying to contend with soft deletes, I'd look at data filters on your DAL instead. AspNetBoilderplate has some good ideas you could use for inspiration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening (most likely) is Moq can't match `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` when you do the `.Setup()`.

So instead you can use `IsAny<>()` approach:

```
_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>())).Returns(foos);
```

If you want to assert what expression is passed in, try

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> capturedExpression = null; 
_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>()))
.Returns((Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> e ) => { capturedExpression = e; return foos; }); 
Assert.IsTrue(capturedExpression.Compile()(_foos[1])); 
Assert.IsFalse(capturedExpression.Compile()(_foos[0]));
```

to verify the method was called you can also change the last it a bit more:

```
_fooRepository.Setup(m => m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>()))
.Returns((Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> e ) => { capturedExpression = e; return foos; })
.Verifiable();
```

then `_fooRepository.Verify(m=>m.GetList(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>()), Times.Once());` However, if it is not called, then capturedExpression is null (that technique is known as implicit assertion)